# primefaces tree drag,drop ajax event

Tags: ajax, primefaces, drag-and-drop, tree, tomcat7

I have this error:

> jan 03, 2014 6:43:56 PM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl
>   processPartial INFO: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent cannot be cast to
>   javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent cannot be cast to
>   javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent

Tree in xhtml:

```
                <p:tree id="catTree"
                        value="#{listCatsRenderer.categoryTree}" var="ndt"
                        selectionMode="single" 
                        selection="#{listCatsRenderer.selectedNode}"
                        draggable="true"
                        droppable="true"
                        animate="true" styleClass="tree_general"
                        propagateSelectionUp="false"
                        dynamic="true"
                        >

                    <p:ajax event="dragdrop" listener="#{listCatsRenderer.onDragDrop}" update=":main:catTree"/>

                    <p:treeNode>
                        <p:inplace event="dblclick" editor="true" >
                            <h:inputText value="#{ndt.name}"/>
                        </p:inplace>
                    </p:treeNode>  
                </p:tree>
```

Loading from bean is here:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ListCatsRenderer extends ARenderer implements Serializable {
.
.
.
@Override
public TreeNode getCategoryTree() {
    if (categoryTree == null) {
        updateCategoryTree(); //DBS load
    } 
    return categoryTree;
}
```

After any dragdrop event it throws exception. When I turn of condition above, it works without errors. Any idea why ?
Thank you.

//EDIT
Code for process event, however I thing it never gets there

```
public void onDragDrop(TreeDragDropEvent event) {
    System.out.println("dragged: " + event.getDragNode());
    System.out.println("dropped: " + event.getDropNode() + " > " + event.getDropIndex());
}
```

And full stacktrace, might help:

> jan 05, 2014 11:50:28 AM
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase execute WARNING:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent
>   cannot be cast to javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent
>   javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent cannot be cast to
>   javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent   at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:270)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationFilter.doFilter(ConversationFilter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)  Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent
>   cannot be cast to javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent      at
>   org.primefaces.component.tree.Tree.queueEvent(Tree.java:308)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.queueEvent(UIComponentBase.java:1057)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.queueEvent(UIComponentBase.java:1057)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.queueEvent(UIComponentBase.java:1057)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:992)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.inplace.Inplace.processValidators(Inplace.java:218)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.processColumnChildren(UITree.java:442)
>     at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.processNode(UITree.java:372)
>     at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.processNode(UITree.java:380)
>     at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.processNodes(UITree.java:365)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.processValidators(UITree.java:308)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.tree.Tree.processValidators(Tree.java:377)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:552)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
>     at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.visitTree(UITree.java:552)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)    at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:263)
>     ... 28

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with Mojarra 2.0.3 (FCS b03), PrimeFaces 4.0.

Please tell us more about the versions you use and provide the exact code for onDragDrop method of your backing bean. I guess it is related to your method that is not using the right parameter types (**TreeDragDropEvent** is expected, not ***ValueChangeEvent***).

Should be something like :

```
public void onDragDrop(TreeDragDropEvent event) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have exactly same onDragDrop method with same parameter. This exception is thrown even when I dont use <p:ajax event="dragdrop" listener="#{listCatsRenderer.onDragDrop}" update=":main:catTree"/>, therefore method should not be called. PrimeFaces 4, Tomcat 7, JSF 2.2, Weld 2.0.4

Comment: Your tree contains inputs : Possible PF issue 6380 fixed in PF 4.0.5, see https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6380

Comment: Seems legit :) I try to update and keep you posted. Thank you so far ;)